# A nonzero compact operator on a Hilbert space has a nonzero eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Let $T:H\to H$ be a compact operator on a Hilbert space $H$, with $T\neq0$. Prove that $\exists c\neq0$ and $x\neq0$ such that $Tx=cx$.

I was trying to prove it using the fact that if $T$ is a compact and $S=I-T$  then either the nullspace of $S\neq0$ or the range of $S$ is $H$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "Help" is a good thing, but it is relative to the background of the Reader.  Please fill in some context, e.g. your understanding of the problem and specific difficulties in trying your own approach.  Is $H$ a Hilbert space?

Comment: Your theorem is true if $T$ is normal though because in that case $\|T\| = r(T)$, the spectral radius, and so $T$ has a non-zero spectral value, which must be an eigen-value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question says that for any compact operator $T:H\to H$ there exists a non-zero eigenvalue, i.e, the point spectrum $\sigma_p(T) \neq \{0\}$. But this is not true as you can see from the following example.

Define $T: l^2 \to l^2$ by 
\begin{equation}
T((x_1,x_2,\ldots)) = \left(\frac{x_2}{1},\frac{x_3}{2},\ldots,\right).
\end{equation}
Now you can check that $T$ defined above is compact but $\sigma_p(T) = \{0\}$.

$\textbf{Note}:$ Though it is true that if $T:H\to H$ is a compact operator then every spectral value $\lambda \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue. But this does not says that there will exist a non-zero eigenvalue as can be seen by the above example.